# Explain data revalidation in Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server

Quick question about server actions and route handlers in next js 13; these data fetching methods are generating next js APIs to allow the client to communicate with them, which is pretty cool. However, I am not performing actions DIRECTLY to my database. In one use case, I have an external API I have developed in C#, and in another case I am utilizing the API generated by Supabase.

So, I can't find any information talking about best practices when communicating with an external API. Does it make sense to use server actions or route handlers for external api calls, rather than direct database calls?

Since I do have dedicated apis running on dedicated servers, does it even make sense to be fetching data from the server in next js, since the apis already live on the server? I might have a misunderstanding regarding the way that next js generates these APIs - some clarification sure would be helpful!